# React Native - Firebase Microsoft Authentication - Error: `new OAuthProvider()` is not supported on the native Firebase SDKs

Tags: android, firebase, azure, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to add a microsoft login to my react native app with the help of firebase. I have done all the preconfiguration in both azure portal and firebase. The issue seems to be with the error (see title).

I'm following this guide : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth#web-version-9

And once i try to create an instance of OauthProvider, i get the error. Here's the specific code (also found in the guide) :

```
const provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');
```

Ive looked around and i think there's a couple of hacks for others login such as facebook but i didnt find anything for microsoft yet. It also seems to be the simplier way to implement a login to microsoft button. Simply put, im literally stuck at the first step so if there's an alternative or a way to fix that real quick, i'd appreciate it. Thanks !

Comment: running into this any luck?